# Is there a way to see when someone stops viewing your video using PHP or JavaScript?

Tags: php, video, web-analytics

If I were to have a video on a webpage, and have someone watch it but stop midway through, is there a way to see where they stopped? (i.e. 42 seconds into it.) Either using HTML5, PHP, JavaScript, or any combination thereof?

Comment: Not that I know of, you can only do this manually by taking over the user's camera, and if he turned from smile to a frown then he is not viewing your video anymore. (Caveat: this is a joke)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible with HTML 5 and JavaScript. You need to register an event handler for the video's `pause` event, then read the `currentTime` playback attribute:

```
<video id="myVideo" width="320" height="240" controls="controls">
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>

<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("myVideo").addEventListener("pause", function() {
    alert("Video paused at " + vid.currentTime);
});
</script>
```

`currentTime` will be the time at which the video was paused in seconds.

Of course, the `pause` event won't fire if they navigate away from the page before the video finishes.

Comment: Could add <body onunload="pauseme()">